# Upgrading pip before compiling Python?

Tags: python, pip

So, I was building Python to optimize it to my hardware (specifically, version 3.6.7) and in the verbose I found this suggestion:

> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Can I upgrade pip before issuing the build command (compile python on my machine)? If so, will it matter?

Comment: You don't have to. This is the version bundled with Python 3.6, nothing wrong with using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your `python` task without upgrading. You can upgrade `pip` if you want (`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`), but I don't think the running of your `python` task will be affected by it.